# How can I create a nested mat-select in Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material

I'm new to Angular so if my question is too noobie, please understand.

I have a data structure something like this:

```
export class Category {

    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public name: string,
        public hasChild: boolean,
        public parent: string,
        public uri: string
    ) { }

}



export class CategoryTreeItem {
    constructor(
      public category: Category,
      public children: CategoryTreeItem[]
    ) {}

    static createCategoryTree(categories: Category[], parent: string): CategoryTreeItem[] {
        const tree: CategoryTreeItem[] = [];
        const mainCats = categories.filter(cat => cat.parent === parent);

        mainCats.forEach(cat => {
            if (cat.hasChild) {
                const subCats = this.getCategoryTree(categories, cat.id);
                tree.push(new CategoryTreeItem(cat, subCats));
            } else {
                tree.push(new CategoryTreeItem(cat, null));
            }
        });

        return tree;
    }
  }
```

And here is a sample output:

```
CategoryTreeItem.createCategoryTree(aCategoryArray, null);
// second parameter is null, since I want to get a full tree. 
// If I want to start the tree from a specific category, I can give it's ID.

// this will return a data like this:

[
    1: CategoryTreeItem {
        category: Category {
            name: A,
            hasChild: true,
            parent: null,
            uri: a
        },
        children: [
            1: CategoryTreeItem {
                category: Category {
                    name: B,
                    hasChild: false,
                    parent: A,
                    uri: b
                }
                children: null // null since B.hasChild = false
            }
        ]
    }, 
    2: CategoryTreeItem {
        category: Category {
            name: C,
            hasChild: false,
            parent: null,
            uri: c
        },
        children: null // null since C.hasChild = false
    }
    3: CategoryTreeItem {
        category: Category {
            name: D,
            hasChild: true,
            parent: null,
            uri: d
        },
        children: [
            1: CategoryTreeItem {
                category: Category {
                    name: E,
                    hasChild: true,
                    parent: D,
                    uri: e
                }
                children: [
                    // more children since E.hasChild = true
                ]
            },
            2: CategoryTreeItem {
                category: Category {
                    name: F,
                    hasChild: false,
                    parent: D,
                    uri: f
                }
                children: null // null since F.hasChild = false
            }
        ]
    }, 
]
```

My problem is I have no idea to create a mat-select with this data.

Here is what I tried to do for now:

- If a category does have a child category, it should be a `<mat-optgroup>` and not selectable. In my data structure, products cannot refer to a category which has child categories.
- Categories with no child category are going to be `<mat-option>` placed in it's parent's opt-group.

This way I'm going to have a tree-like-looking mat-select, at least this is what I expect.

Thank you.

Comment: this is complicated but if use recursive template this can be done

Comment: @Asanka I decided to not to go ahead, instead, I filtered categories and created a single branched array. Each category name now contains parent's too; like:

"aCategory => aCategory => aCategory"